# customizing android ToggleButton display text

Tags: android, formatting, togglebutton

Recently my ToggleButtons on an application I'm working on lost it's green light indicator. I started with the various tutorials and got together a set of 9 patch indicators to make them work correctly again. The only problem is the text now sits on top of the indicator, like so:

[image: toggle buttons]

I would like the text on top like the old toggle buttons...is there any way to do this?

btn_toggle_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_default" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/toggle" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle" />
    </layer-list>
```

my btn_toggle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle_off" />
    </selector>
```

and the togglebutton tag in my activity:

```
        <ToggleButton 
            android:background="@drawable/btn_toggle_bg"
            style="@style/OurThemeName" 
            android:textOff="@string/fertilizer" 
            android:textOn="@string/fertilizer" 
            android:id="@+id/toggleFertilizer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false">
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton 
            android:background="@drawable/btn_toggle_bg"
            style="@style/OurThemeName" 
            android:textOff="@string/irrigation" 
            android:textOn="@string/irrigation" 
            android:id="@+id/toggleIrrigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false">
        </ToggleButton>
```

almost forgot the themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- Overwrite the ToggleButton style -->
<style name="Widget.Button.Toggle" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_toggle_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textOn">On</item>
    <item name="android:textOff">Off</item>
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">?android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
</style>

<style name="OurThemeName"  parent="@android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/Widget.Button.Toggle</item>
      <item name="android:textOn"></item>
    <item name="android:textOff"></item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I ended up just using the holo theme 9 patch togglebuttons. you can find them in the drawable folder along with the default toggle buttons and they are formatted correctly already to put text on and such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the **Fill Area** in your 9-Patch. You can add this areas including them in the right and bottom of your images using the **Draw 9-patch** tool. With this you are defining the area for your text label.

Check [this tutorial](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) explaining how 9-Patch works.

Comment: Yeah it looks like this is what I needed...I have the indicator light all off center now though so I'll play with it